# How to model up votes and down votes for posts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an app that allows user to post. Each post can be upvoted and downvoted. Each user also has reputation calculated from the upvotes and downvotes from their posts. Now, I keep track of the upvotes and downvotes of each post in two places. Firstly, there is my posts table:

```
 create_table "posts", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.text     "content"
    t.integer  "upvotes",    :default => 0
    t.integer  "downvotes",  :default => 0
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
  end
```

I also keep track of each vote with a seperate 'votes' table so that I know which user has voted on a post already (a vote of 0 is no vote, a vote of 1 is a downvote, a vote of 2 is an upvote):

```
create_table "votes", :force => true do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "post_id"
    t.integer  "vote",       :default => 0
    t.datetime "created_at",                :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                :null => false
  end
```

I originally kept track of the post votes in two different tables to make it more efficient to query the number of votes a specific post has, for example, this:

```
post_reputation = post.upvotes - post.downvotes
```

However, I am now thinking that this is bad practice and that I should delete the 'upvotes' and 'downvotes' column on my 'posts' table so that vote data is not duplicated. I would then calculate post reputation doing something like this:

```
def calculate_post_reputation(post_id)
  some_post = Post.find(post_id)
  vote_count = 0
  some_post.votes.each do |vote|
    if vote.vote.to_i == 2
      vote_count += 1
    elsif vote.vote.to_i == 1
      vote_count -= 1
    end
   end
  vote_count
end
```

Is it better to keep the 'upvotes' and 'downvotes' columns or delete them and use the 'votes' table to calculate post reputation?

Answer (score 0):

I would consider (pseudo code):

```
Models:

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
  has_many :posts, :through => votes

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :votes
  has_many :users, :though => :votes

class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
  attr_accessor :direction
  UP='Up'
  DOWN='Down'
  DIRECTIONS=[UP,DOWN]
  validates_inclusion_of :direction, in: [DIRECTIONS]
  scope :up_votes where(:direction => UP) 
  scope :down_votes where(:direction => DOWN)
```

Then use `Post.votes.up_votes.count` and `Post.votes.down_votes.count` for number of up or down votes.

The approach you have outlined is how I used to tackle it in SQL, the above is a more rails style approach.   You would need to add the appropriate db migrations.